# How to derive multiple classes from a single nib

Tags: xcode, nib

I’m trying to create a nib for a generic SectionHeader for a TableView as I need several similar SectionHeaders. I’m trying to follow this SO post:

[How to create multiple windows with the same nib file in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117753/how-to-create-multiple-windows-with-the-same-nib-file-in-xcode)

The view defined in my nib file is assigned a base class of BaseSectionHeader. Here’s its initializer:

```
BaseSectionHeader.m
- (id) initWithController:(MasterViewController*)ctlr;
{
    self = [[[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SectionHeader" bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:ctlr options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    if (self)
    {
        _controller = ctlr;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Here’s the initializer of a subclass I’d like to derive:

SectionHeader.h

```
@interface SectionHeader : BaseSectionHeader <UIAlertViewDelegate>
…
@end
```

SectionHeader.m

```
- (id) initWithController:(MasterViewController*)ctlr
{
    if (self = [super initWithController:ctlr])
    {
        _deleteConfirmButtonWidth = 70.0;
    }

    return self;
}
```

And here’s how I instantiate a section header:

```
MasterViewController.m
…
    SectionHeader* hdr = [[SectionHeader alloc] initWithController:self];
…
```

The problem is hdr is returned as a BaseSectionHeader, not a SectionHeader. This works correctly if I don't use the nib and construct BaseSectionHeader manually in code. But I’d like to use IB to construct the BaseSectionHeader if I can.

Why is hdr a BaseSectionHeader instead of a SectionHeader when I use a nib? Is there a way use the nib and get the subclass I want for hdr?

FWIW here’s my manual code:

```
BaseSectionHeader.m
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 275.0, 40.0)];
        [_label setTextColor:TanColor];
        [_label setNumberOfLines:2];
        [_label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
        [_label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
        [self addSubview:_label];
    }

    return self;
}

SectionHeader.m
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame Controller:(MasterViewController*)ctlr
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        _controller = ctlr;
        _deleteConfirmButtonWidth = 70.0;

        _titleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        _titleButton.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 275.0, 40.0);
        _titleButton.alpha = 0.3;
        [self addSubview:_titleButton];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, a nib is used to instantiate an object whose code stands alone. The nib for objectX is not used within the code of objectX.

When SectionHeader is allocated, and its init called, it passes itself to the BaseSectionHeader version of the same method.  But BaseSectionHeader drops that and creates a new object to put in self.  Thus a SectionHeader is replaced with a BaseSectionHeader.

The UINib calls to instantiate should be made in MasterViewController.

Comment: Thanks. I had noticed that the type of self changed from SectionHeader to BaseSectionHeader during the call to BaseSectionHeader.initWithController. So a call to instantiateWithOwner is not analogous to an init call and therefore it is not possible to derive from an object defined in a nib?

Comment: No.  The nib specifies the exact class to be used at runtime.  Think of the nib as a combination of the class to instantiate and the values to be put into various members after instantiation.